# When I use the Keybert, I encountered this problem。

Tags: python, bert-language-model

How can I solve this?

**Error:**

ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/models/sentence-transformers/paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error')))

**And the Code**

```
doc = """
         Supervised learning is the machine learning task of learning a function that
         maps an input to an output based on example input-output pairs. It infers a
         function from labeled training data consisting of a set of training examples.
         In supervised learning, each example is a pair consisting of an input object
         (typically a vector) and a desired output value (also called the supervisory signal). 
         A supervised learning algorithm analyzes the training data and produces an inferred function, 
         which can be used for mapping new examples. An optimal scenario will allow for the 
         algorithm to correctly determine the class labels for unseen instances. This requires 
         the learning algorithm to generalize from the training data to unseen situations in a 
         'reasonable' way (see inductive bias).
      """

kw_model = KeyBERT(model='paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2')

print("naive ...")
keywords = kw_model.extract_keywords(doc)
print(keywords)
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? How to learn a library "xyz"? I'd start with googling a tutorial, follow along and read the docs of the vital parts simultaneously. I doubt, that somebody in SO will teach you via a single answer/comment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry, because the first time I use this site, I'm not proficient and missed the question.

Comment: The solution to the problem is to turn off the proxy server.